# Trying to pass database name and text to call a SQL command in different file

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm calling the following code:

```
public static bool checkDuplicateProducts(string item1, string item2)
{
    // new connection
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(stringCon);

    // adapter query
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM '" + item1 + "' WHERE ProductCode='" + item2 + "'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

from this:

```
string tableName = "Product";
else if(Functions.checkDuplicateProducts(tableName, textBox2.Text) == true)
{
       MessageBox.Show("The id is already available", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I get this error when doing so:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ' Product '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *table* shouldn't be *single quoted* i.e `SELECT * FROM table_name`

```
"SELECT * FROM '" + item1 + "'
```

Should be

```
"SELECT * FROM " + item1 + "
```

However, you should really be using *parameterised queries* in general, lest you be on the wrong end of an *sql injection attack*

Comment: I'm a noob, and yeah that is what i'm trying to do. so what i'm doing is correct yeah?

Comment: @HasaraJayasinghe yes it should work if corrected. however try to use Parameterised queries.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from Table Name`  you Should by Not Accepted c# for the query in `'Table Name'`

**REPLACE THE CODE**

```
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + item1 + " WHERE ProductCode='" + item2 + "'", con);
```